# CSS Grid - position text in three columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid, css-grid

currently I’m struggling with positioning these 3 text columns just like in picture. Each column contains 3 patagraphs.

Problem is, paragraph’s width is not equal, so `grid-template-columns:repeat(3, 1fr)` is not ideal solution because second and third paragraph will have unnecessary big white-space and that’s the problem when responsibility comes in. (Layout will break very soon because of that white-space).

I’ve tried `min-content` or `max-content` atributes but still I can’t figure it out, so it will look just as in the picture.

So goal is to align columns and paragraphs in it just like in the picture but without unwanted whitespace so work with responsibility will be easier.

Is there any better solution for it?

I have tried my best, here’s [codepen](https://codepen.io/pinnci/pen/RwVNayW)

Thank you!

[image: goal picture]

Comment: a grid display requires a single parent from which you set that grid. then auto will size the column from the widdest content or cells that it holds. justify-content will tell how it should be layed. start,center,end, ... a possible example https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/VwbYaqL

Comment: So you want the content to dictate the width of the columns?

Comment: ... this could be a real table too ... there is nothing wrong using a table when content deserves it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `minmax` in your `grid-template-column` property, `minmax(5rem, 10rem) minmax(3rem, 5rem) auto;`, this will set the **minimum** width of the *first column* to **5rem** and the **maximum** width to **10rem**, the *second* to **min** of **3rem** and **max** of **5rem**, then the *last columns width* will be the *width of its content* => ***auto***.

[css-grid-layout-minmax ~ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/minmax())

```css
.card {
  background: silver;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.column {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(5rem, 10rem) minmax(3rem, 5rem) auto;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

p:nth-of-type(3),
p:nth-of-type(4),
p:nth-of-type(2) {
  text-align: right;
}

p + p {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="column-wrapper">
    <div class="column">
      <p>lorem:</p>
      <p>282726€</p>
      <p>28%</p>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <p>lorem ipsum:</p>
      <p>287€</p>
      <p>10%</p>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <p>lorem:</p>
      <p>19118€</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```